# How to convert UltraGrid to gridview

Tags: infragistics

Hi In my project we are using third party tool(infragistics) for displaying the data in Grid .now what my question is Is any other way to use normal grid view instead of infragistics.how to change ultra gird to normal grid ..I am new to project .please give me some ideas ..
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to the question is that you change the control and set the DataSource on the new control instead.  Depending on how much code you have, what features of the UltraGrid you are using and which features you need this can become much more complicated.

I believe that you need to lean more about your own project and how the grid is used and do your own analysis on what the impact of the change is.